# simulate "tail -F" on old system

Tags: perl, bash, logging, solaris, tail

Since [file input](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-665) is buggy for logstash on Solaris, I am trying to use the [pipe input](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/pipe) instead. A configuration based on a "tail -f" works great, but the problem is that the file is being rolled over every time it reaches 20MB, which happens about once a week.

So I googled for a way of tailing tolerating rollover and found that [tail -F would be the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647690/tailing-rolling-files?rq=1)... if that command was available on Solaris 10. I also found a [shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985069/improvements-to-this-bash-script-to-simulate-tail-follow) that could do the trick, but the permanent cpu consumption of 1.5% is quite dissuasive.

So I am looking for alternatives. Ideally I would rather not have to install third-party software which requires administration privileges I don't own, or which requires recompilation since there is a very low probability for it to work (there is always some lib version requirement which fails).

I am considering using an enhanced perl script like we can find some when googling on the topic or even make a java interface (but not sure it would cost less resources than the shell script), but before that I was wondering if there was a simpler way around.

How did you do before the -F flag was introduced?

Comment: install the GNU coreutils and use tail from there; there appears to even be a package: http://www.opencsw.org/package/coreutils/

Comment: In case you would not know, you have to pay a subscription to access opencsw packages. But even if I did, I don't own admin rights on the system, so...

Comment: the GNU flavors of several tools are so useful, they often get installed; are you sure they are not already there (in a non-standard path)?  if not, maybe you can get your admin to install them.  see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools for a free source for Solaris 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Perl Power Tools](http://www.metacpan.org/module/PerlPowerTools), a project to *"reimplement the classic Unix command set in pure Perl"*. `tail` is one of the commands that the project implements.

Comment: Wow this is working right and smooth and the cpu consumption is around 0.03%, which is far far better than the shell script. I knew about busybox, but not about those perl scripts. You made my day and this will probably help me in a lot of other situations! I will let this open for two or three days, then come back and probably accept your answer :)

Comment: It'a also a nice way to get Unix commands on a foreign (Windows) platform, and very easy to tweak the commands with your own options. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Borodin Do you know of a convenient way to install `ppt` on a windows system?  Is there a `cpan` method like the way `Mojolicious` automatically sets up `morbo`, `hypnotoad`, and `mojo`?

Comment: @Miller: I'm sorry I overlooked your question. You can install Perl Power Tools by using CPAN to install `PPT::Util`. No such module will actually be installed. Instead you will find shell scripts in (I think) `/usr/local/ppt/bin`.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks, installed.  Noticed a small bug with `awk` when run w/o parameters.  `Use of uninitialized value $tmpin in unlink at C:\usr\local\ppt\bin\awk line 15.`   Care to teach me how to report those warnings?  Doubt things would be updated, but I'd be nice to know how to do that.

Comment: @Borodin `awk` could be fixed by changing line line 15 to: `unlink for grep defined $tmpin, $tmpout; # XXX: don't check failure`

Comment: @Borodin Figured it out.  emailed bug-ppt.